# Sorting strings two times using insertion sort

Tags: sorting, racket, insertion-sort

I am trying to sort a (listof (listof Str Str)) using insertion sort, but I don't know how to proceed from here. Firstly, it has to alphabetically sort by the first strings, then alphabetically by the second string.
For example:

```
(list (list "produce" "apple")
    (list "seed" "rice")
    (list "dairy" "milk" )
    (list "seed" "pinto")
    (list "produce" "potato")
    (list "chips" "potato")
    (list "seed" "wheat")
    (list "produce" "banana")
    (list "dairy" "cheese")
    (list "chips" "banana")
    (list "produce" "peach")
    (list "seed" "lentil")
    (list "produce" "corn")
    (list "seed" "corn")) becomes


`(list (list "chips" "banana") (list "chips" "potato") (list "dairy" "cheese") (list "dairy" "kefir") (list "dairy" "milk")` (list "chips" "potato")  (list "dairy" "cheese") (list "dairy" "kefir") (list "dairy" "milk") (list "produce" "apple") (list "produce" "banana" (list "produce" "corn")(list "produce" "peach")(list "produce" "potato")(list "seed" "corn")(list "seed" "lentil")(list "seed" "pinto"))
```

May I know what is the approach after I wrote the code that sorts the input list of lists by the first string? After sorting by the first string, the list looks like this:

```
(list ("chips" "potato") (list "chips" "banana") (list "dairy" "milk")(list "dairy" "cheese")(list "dairy" "kefir")(list "produce" "apple")(list "produce" "potato") (list "produce" "banana")(list "produce" "peach")(list "produce" "corn")(list "seed" "rice")(list "seed" "pinto")(list "seed" "wheat")(list "seed" "lentil")(list "seed" "corn"))
```

How can I sort the list by the second string? Greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't know much about Racket but the usual way to do that in many language would be to swap the first and the second string and then apply a standard sort and then again swap the two string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [sort](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._sort%29%29) function together with [string-append](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._string-append%29%29)

```
(define (sort-items lst)
    (sort lst string<? #:key
        (lambda (n)
            (string-append (car n) (cadr n)))))
```

Comment: May I know how to sort this list without using lambda?

Comment: To my knowledge, you need to use a lambda function to do this. But, also I could be wrong.

Comment: @EmilyW `lambda` just like define a local function than use in this place. Also I think @Lahiru already solve your question. If it does. Please accept answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Lahiru answer is great.
I show another version.

```
#lang racket

(define lst
  '(("a" "a")
    ("b" "a")
    ("c" "z")
    ("c" "a")
    ("b" "z")
    ("d" "a")
    ("a" "z")
    ("d" "z")))

(define (sort-items-index lst)
  (local [(define index-lst
            (map (λ (s) (string-length (first s))) lst))
          (define (combile-2-str s)
            (string-append (first s) (second s)))
          (define (spilt-str-by-index s n)
            (list (substring s 0 n) (substring s n (string-length s))))]
    (map spilt-str-by-index
         (sort (map combile-2-str lst) string<?)
         index-lst)))

(sort-items-index lst)

(define (sort-items-v2 lst)
  (sort lst (λ (s1 s2)
              (string<?
               (string-append (first s1) (second s1))
               (string-append (first s2) (second s2))))))
        
(sort-items-v2 lst)
```